# How to create menuItem dynamically

Tags: java, android, android-studio, menu

I have an app which has a menu (3 items) that is obtained from a resource xml menu.

[image]

The third item in the menu (Insert) should make visible a `button` and an editable Text box that I have, `editText`.

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu ( Menu menu ) {
        getMenuInflater ().inflate (R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

 

       @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected ( @NonNull MenuItem item ) {
            switch (item.getItemId ()){
                case R.id.menu1:
                    return true;
                case R.id.menu2:
                    return true;
                case R.id.menu3:
                    editText.setVisibility (View.VISIBLE);
                    button.setVisibility (View.VISIBLE);
                default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected (item);
            }
        }
```

Once both are visible, when I tap add button, I want to create a menu item dynamically titled with the input edit text.
Is it possible?
I tried using this but it isn't working, perhaps because I created a new menu whereas I only want to create an item.

```
button.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener () {
            @Override
            public void onClick ( View v ) {

                mi = new Menu () {
                    @Override
                    public MenuItem add ( CharSequence title ) {

                        return null;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public MenuItem add ( int titleRes ) {
                        return null;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public MenuItem add ( int groupId, int itemId, int order, CharSequence title ) {
                        return null;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public MenuItem add ( int groupId, int itemId, int order, int titleRes ) {
                        mi.add (0,4,4,"New Menu taken from edittext");
                        return null;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public SubMenu addSubMenu ( CharSequence title ) {
                        return null;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public SubMenu addSubMenu ( int titleRes ) {
                        return null;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public SubMenu addSubMenu ( int groupId, int itemId, int order, CharSequence title ) {
                        return null;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public SubMenu addSubMenu ( int groupId, int itemId, int order, int titleRes ) {
                        return null;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public int addIntentOptions ( int groupId, int itemId, int order, ComponentName caller, Intent[] specifics, Intent intent, int flags, MenuItem[] outSpecificItems ) {
                        return 0;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void removeItem ( int id ) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void removeGroup ( int groupId ) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void clear () {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void setGroupCheckable ( int group, boolean checkable, boolean exclusive ) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void setGroupVisible ( int group, boolean visible ) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void setGroupEnabled ( int group, boolean enabled ) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean hasVisibleItems () {
                        return false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public MenuItem findItem ( int id ) {
                        return null;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public int size () {
                        return 0;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public MenuItem getItem ( int index ) {
                        return null;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void close () {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean performShortcut ( int keyCode, KeyEvent event, int flags ) {
                        return false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean isShortcutKey ( int keyCode, KeyEvent event ) {
                        return false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean performIdentifierAction ( int id, int flags ) {
                        return false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void setQwertyMode ( boolean isQwerty ) {

                    }
                };
```

Could someone help me wiht it?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`add`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Menu#add(int,%20int,%20int,%20java.lang.CharSequence)) method in the `Menu` class.

For example:

```
toolbar.getMenu().add( Menu.NONE, 100 , Menu.NONE, "New Item");
```

or if you have an item defined in a menu file:

```
toolbar.getMenu().add( Menu.NONE, R.id.action_xxxx, order , "Text");
```

with:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

@Gabrile Mariotti

No errors but no add item

[image]

```
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

button.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener () {
    @Override
    public void onClick ( View v ) {

        Toolbar toolbar =  findViewById (R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.getMenu ().add (Menu.NONE, R.menu.menu, Menu.NONE,"New tem");

    }
});
```

It's clear but i don't understand why not work.... following the code

MainActivity

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText editText;
    private Button button;
    private Menu menu;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate ( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
        super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);
        setContentView (R.layout.activity_main);

        editText = findViewById (R.id.editText);
        button = findViewById (R.id.addButton);
        Toolbar toolbar =  findViewById (R.id.toolbar);

        button.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener () {
            @Override
            public void onClick ( View v ) {
                Toolbar toolbar =  findViewById (R.id.toolbar);
                toolbar.getMenu ().add (Menu.NONE,100,Menu.NONE,"titolo");
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu ( Menu menu ) {
        getMenuInflater ().inflate (R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected ( @NonNull MenuItem item ) {
        switch (item.getItemId ()){
            case R.id.menu1:
                return true;
            case R.id.menu2:
                return true;
            case R.id.menu3:
                editText.setVisibility (View.VISIBLE);
                button.setVisibility (View.VISIBLE);
            default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected (item);
        }
    }
}
```

XML

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/addButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ADD"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.47"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.241" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="528dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text=""
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.454"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.231" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="102dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/editText"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

Menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item android:id="@+id/menu1"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    app:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/menu_1"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/menu2"
        android:orderInCategory="2"
        app:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/menu_2"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/menu3"
        android:orderInCategory="3"
        app:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="insert"/>
</menu>
```

Comment: You are adding `R.menu.menu`. In my code I am using `R.id.action.`. It is not a menu, but an item defined in a menu.

Comment: The Item is new, so is not defined in menu.xml
<menu>
    <item android:id="@+id/menu1"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    app:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/menu_1"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/menu2"
        android:orderInCategory="2"
        app:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/menu_2"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/menu3"
        android:orderInCategory="3"
        app:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="insert"/>
</menu>